# set 2 ARCHFLAGS when installing numpy

Tags: numpy, installation, flags

I am trying to install numpy for python 2.7, Mac OS X 10.8. 
First, I installed with this command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Due to the error: `RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program`, I need to set ARCHFLAGS:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install --upgrade numpy
```

This helped installing numpy but when I tried to import numpy it gave error for multiarray.so in numpy: `mach-o, but wrong architecture`

I checked:

```
$ arch
i386
$ file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

According to one answer on Stack Overflow, I need to set arch to i386 like this:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" pip install numpy
```

However, I don't know how to combine two ARCHFLAGS together, I tried:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=["-arch=i386","-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"] pip install --upgrade numpy
```

but it didn't work. Could someone show me how to set multi ARCHFLAGS in one command please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" pip install numpy
```

ARCHFLAGS is just passed to some other command, so separating commands with a space will use both.